# Efficiently find overlapping JodaTime Intervals

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `Seq` of Intervals and I want to collapse overlapping ones into each other.
I've written this:

```
val today = DateTime.now()
val a: Seq[Interval] = Seq(
  new Interval(today.minusDays(11), today.minusDays(10)), //1 day interval ending 10 days ago
  new Interval(today.minusDays(10), today.minusDays(8)), //2 day interval ending 8 days ago, overlaps with above
  new Interval(today.minusDays(7), today.minusDays(5)), //2 day interval ending 5 days ago, DOES NOT OVERLAP
  new Interval(today.minusDays(4), today.minusDays(1)), //3 day interval ending 1 day ago, DOES NOT OVERLAP above
  new Interval(today.minusDays(4), today) //4 day interval ending today, overlaps with above
)
val actual = a.sortBy(_.getStartMillis).foldLeft(Seq[Interval]())((vals, e) => {
  if (vals.isEmpty) {
    vals ++ Seq(e)
  } else {
    val fst = vals.last
    val snd = e
    if (snd.getStart.getMillis <= fst.getEnd.getMillis) /*they overlap*/ {
      vals.dropRight(1) ++ Seq(new Interval(fst.getStart, snd.getEnd)) //combine both into one interval
    } else {
      vals ++ Seq(e)
    }
  }
})
val expected = Seq(
  new Interval(today.minusDays(11), today.minusDays(8)),
  new Interval(today.minusDays(7), today.minusDays(5)),
  new Interval(today.minusDays(4), today)
)
println(
  s"""
     |Expected: $expected
     |Actual  : $actual
   """.stripMargin)
assert(expected == actual)
```

which works. My initial concern was with the line
`vals.dropRight(1) ++ Seq(new Interval(fst.getStart, snd.getEnd))`

I suspect `dropRight` is `O(n - m)` where `n = |vals|` and `m = 1` in this case.

This implementation becomes expensive if `|a|` is in the order of hundreds of thousands or more. In fact `vals ++ Seq(e)` is also an issue if it does `n + 1` for each `a[i]`.

Firstly, is my assessment correct?

Second, is there a more efficient way to write this without mutable data structures?

I've written this out of the context it's being used in, the actual application is in a Spark job (so that `foldLeft` would be folding on an `RDD[MyType]`).

**EDIT** : Completely forgot there's no `foldLeft` on an `RDD` (ignore Spark I'll have to think of another way but I'm still interested in an answer to this, minus the fact it won't work in Spark)

Comment: There is no foldLeft or dropRight on RDD.

Comment: Thanks, had completely forgotten there's no `foldLeft` on an RDD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the IntervalSeq[A] and IntervalTrie[A] data structures in the [spire math library](https://github.com/non/spire). IntervalTrie[A] allows doing boolean operations such as union and intersection of sets of non-overlapping intervals with extremely high performance. It requires the element type to be losslessly convertable to a long, which is the case for joda DateTime.

Here is how you would solve this problem using spire:

First, make sure you have the right dependencies. Add a dependency to spire extras to your *build.sbt*:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.spire-math" %% "spire-extras" % "0.12.0"
```

Next, you need to define a *IntervalTrie.Element* typeclass instance for *org.joda.time.DateTime*:

```
implicit val jodaDateTimeIsIntervalTrieElement: IntervalTrie.Element[DateTime] = new IntervalTrie.Element[DateTime] {
  override implicit val order: Order[DateTime] = Order.by(_.getMillis)
  override def toLong(value: DateTime): Long = value.getMillis
  override def fromLong(key: Long): DateTime = new DateTime(key)
}
```

Now, you can use IntervalTrie to perform boolean operations on DateTime intervals (note that Interval here refers to the generic interval type spire.math.Interval, not joda Interval),

```
// import the Order[DateTime] instance (for spire.math.Interval creation)
import jodaDateTimeIsIntervalTrieElement.order

// create 100000 random Interval[DateTime]
val r = new scala.util.Random()
val n = 100000
val intervals = (0 until n).map { i =>
  val ticks = r.nextInt(1000000000) * 2000L
  val t0 = new DateTime(ticks)
  val t1 = new DateTime(ticks + r.nextInt(1000000000))
  val i = IntervalTrie(spire.math.Interval(t0, t1))
  i
}

//compute the union of all of them using IntervalTrie
val t0 = System.nanoTime()
val union = intervals.foldLeft(IntervalTrie.empty[DateTime])(_ | _)
val dt = (System.nanoTime() - t0) / 1.0e9
println(s"Union of $n random intervals took $dt seconds!")
```

This is very fast. On my machine:

```
Union of 100000 random intervals took 0.045001056 seconds!
```

Doing a proper benchmark with warmup will make this even faster.

Comment: I'll have a look at how those are implemented. Thanks